# generate automatically roles and rights for ssas tabular

Tags: ssas, powerbi, tabular, ssas-tabular

I'd like to defines some user-rights, enabling some basic users only to see there own element in a Sales-Dimension for example, and Team-Leader beeing able to see the whole team.

I have this information in tables, but I didn't found anything to import or set this rights automatically in SSAS, all documentations I have found, show how to do it manually with the gui, but with 500 user, I don't want to do it that way...

Comment: See the [Microsoft.AnalysisServices package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AnalysisServices.retail.amd64/). [Explained for >=1200 compatibility level](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/analysis-services/tabular-model-programming-compatibility-level-1200/introduction-to-the-tabular-object-model-tom-in-analysis-services-amo?view=sql-server-2017). [Explained for 1103 compatibility level](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/analysis-services/tabular-model-programming-compatibility-levels-1050-1103/representation/understanding-tabular-object-model-at-levels-1050-through-1103)

Answer (score 1):

If all the users that you're looking to generate roles for are members of the same role, you can generate a script for the role and run this.  Once connected to the SSAS instance in SSMS, expand the **Roles** folder, right-click the role you want to generate a script for, select **Script Role as**, and choose the action you want to script.  The example below uses the Create or Replace to option.  This is using TMSL which is for compatibility level 1200 or higher.  If your model is below this, you'll use XMLA.  The `tablePermissions` option is in case you use row level security.

```
{
"createOrReplace": {
"object": {
"database": "YourTabularDatabase",
"role": "YourRole"
},
"role": {
   "name": "YourRole",
   "modelPermission": "read",
   "members": [
    {
    "memberName": "domain\\UserNameForRoleMember",
    "memberId": "MemberUID"
    },
    {
    "memberName": "domain\\UserNameForNextRoleMember",
    "memberId": "NextMemberUID"
    }
   ],
   "tablePermissions": [
      {
        "name": "TableWithRowFilters",
        "filterExpression": "DAXFilterExpression"
       }
      ]
     }
    }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple of options:

- [Dynamic Security using the DAX USERNAME() function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/analysis-services/supplemental-lesson-implement-dynamic-security-by-using-row-filters?view=sql-server-2017). This is probably the best solution, since you already have the user/role information in a table.
- Script the roles either using [TOM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/analysis-services/tabular-model-programming-compatibility-level-1200/introduction-to-the-tabular-object-model-tom-in-analysis-services-amo?view=sql-server-2017) or [TMSL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/analysis-services/tabular-model-scripting-language-tmsl-reference) as suggested above. You may also consider using the [scripting functionality of Tabular Editor](https://github.com/otykier/TabularEditor/wiki/Advanced-Scripting), which is similar to TOM, but has the advantage that you can interactively test the scripts.